# Connect express backend to React frontend (in the same server if possible)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I saw a lot of ways to connect React frontend to express backend (REST API) and i don't understand which one of the them is the most common, organized and friendly. (Axios, componentDidMount function and so on..).
My project divide to backend and frontend libraries which includes a connection to mongoDB in the backend.
I am new to React so i will appreciate any recommendation.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily have both on the same server, all you need to do is. Make an express route that servers your react app's `index.html`.

```js
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile('./public/index.html');
});
```

Also, don't forget to serve your static files (`css`, `fonts`, etc) using express's own middleware.

```js
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

After you have done that, you can have your API at `/api`.

Comment: Yes. You can setup a reverse proxy in nginx to assign some routes to the React App and some to express.